# Can you depreciate real estate that has previously been fully depreciated?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, real-estate, depreciation

If you buy a property that is 39 years old and has already been fully depreciated, can you depreciate it again, for another 39 years upon your purchase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By asking about 39 years, I assume you mean a commercial property, as residential is 27.5.

Yes, the depreciation starts when you buy it, the history doesn't matter. It's as plain as that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (between commercial vs residential).

Comment: Most welcome. You can accept the answer if you feel it adequately answered your question.